# Watermark with paperclip 2.7.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, watermark

I want to add watermark on photos while uploading with paperclip
I've got same errors as stated at [this article](http://exviva.posterous.com/watermarking-images-with-rails-3-and-papercli). I've made changes exactly as the author writes, but it didn't work for me.

I've tried another examples, nothing. Updated my paperclip

```
→ bundle list | grep paperclip
  * paperclip (2.7.0)

→ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-linux], MBARI 0x8770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2011.03

→ rails -v
Rails 3.0.10
```

May be that solution doesn't work for newest version of paperclip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution described in my question just not working.
I found [another example](https://gist.github.com/784445) which works for me